# Fail when I try to open the website

Tags: http-status-code-404

The last time I asked a question here, it was fixed very quickly. How can I fix this error? http://wiegexd165.165.axc.nl

Answer (score 0):

Has it ever worked or is this your first time testing this site? If it's never worked and it's a new site, check your Apache config for paths. Are they correct? Maybe try absolute paths. Do you have the directory set to *Deny from all*?

If the site worked but is failing now, what could have changed recently that could have caused it to fail?